# How to Record only My own app audio (not other app or system audio) - Android Studio

Tags: android, audio, record

is there any way to record audio of own app (not other apps or system audio).. i search alot but can't find..

basically im making piano app so i want user record his beat not with mic recording just app audio record.

Android Studio Dev

Comment: Why would you record at all?  There's no analog device here.  Write whatever waveform they're making directly to the sound file.

Comment: Thanks fo4r comment... Basically I'm working on piano app that user can record his beat... Can you explain how to do

Comment: But your app is generating the beat.  So you wouldn't need to record it to get it.  Unless they're adding in additional instruments from outside your app, in which case you'd absolutely have to record the environment.

Comment: It's really not.  I don't think you know what you're doing, or how audio processing works.